# How to check string of one column ,and change of string of another column using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

I have big csv file, PF sample data like below

```
Name,value,data
jack,X16206,hi this is X16206
Riti,X1620600,I want to change X16206.
Aadii,X16206,New value is X1620600.
jan,abc700134,something new 20600.
```

I have a value X16206(alpha-numeric) with 00 added sometimes and sometimes not, in value column and data column
I want to check the string from value column and change the string  present in a sentence which is in the data column as 'exact'

expected output:

```
Name,value,data
jack,X16206,hi this is [exact]
Riti,X1620600,I want to change [exact].
Aadii,X16206,New value is [exact].
jan,abc700134,something new 20600.
```

what I have tried so far

```
df1['num'] = np.where(df1['value'].str.len().isin({6,8}), 1, -1)
def myfn2(row):
    if row['num']==1:
        row['New_data']=row['data'].replace(row['value'],'[exact]')
    else:
        row['New_data']=row['data']
    return row
    
df1=df1.apply(myfn2,axis=1)
```

Output I got

```
Name,value,data,num,New_data
jack,X16206,hi this is X16206,1,hi this is [exact]
Riti,X1620600,I want to change X16206,1,I want to change X16206.
Aadii,X16206,New value is X1620600,1,New value is [exact]00.
jan,abc700134,something new 20600,-1,something new 20600.
```

Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re


def fn(x):
    v = re.sub(r"(?<=\d{4})00$", "", x["value"])
    return re.sub(r"(" + v + "0?0?)", r"[exact]", x["data"])


df["data"] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Name      value                       data
0   jack     X16206         hi this is [exact]
1   Riti   X1620600  I want to change [exact].
2  Aadii     X16206      New value is [exact].
3    jan  abc700134       something new 20600.
```